# How can I set my ajax function to post to the desired PHP POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello how can I set my ajax to POST to the desired PHP POST. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    var feeds = $("#feeds ul");
    var last_time = feeds.children().last().attr('id');
    'url' : '',
    'type' : 'POST',    
    'data' : last_time,     
    'beforeSend' : function () {
        feeds.parents('#feeds').find('.loading').fadeIn();
    },
```

Basically, I want to POST this data to the following PHP POST. Here is the code:

```
     if(isset($_POST['last_time'])){
```

How can I POST my data?

Comment: put the php page name, in url field!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the page name in the url field

```
'url' : 'page_name.php',
```

like below.

```
$.ajax({
var feeds = $("#feeds ul");
var last_time = feeds.children().last().attr('id');
url : 'page_name.php',
type : 'POST',    
data : {last_time:last_time},     
beforeSend : function () {
    feeds.parents('#feeds').find('.loading').fadeIn();
},  
success: function(response)
        {  
            //when response is received do something

        }
    });
```

and on the php

```
if(isset($_POST['last_time'])){
$data = $_POST['last_time']; //use this
}
```